# AWS Nat service is not working with iptable rules

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a public nat instance and private instance with only private ip. Without iptables in nat instance , private instance is getting internet. But after adding iptable rules in nat instance, private instance is not getting internet. I added iptable rules with output drop,input drop ,forward drop chain. After adding this rule nat is not working.

Do I need to add any pre routing or post routing rule to my iptable rule list.

Comment: A NAT instance *already has* iptables rules. That's how it does the NAT.  It sounds like you may be removing them.  List the rules in `--table nat` after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Routing in aws instances can be done in AWS Web Admin Console by assigning a [security group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html). Those groups handle iptables rules sets that can be plugged to your instances. You can attach up to 500 security groups to a classic-ec2 instance.

Using [cli](https://aws.amazon.com/es/cli/) by any of de SDKs available allows you to programatically configure instances.

In other hand it makes a big difference if your instance is a ec2-VPC or ec2-classic. EC2-VPC groups are sligly different in concept therefore have not the same definition and set-up.

If you want to deal with iptables in ec2 instances yourself, have a look at [this](https://wincent.com/wiki/Using_iptables_on_EC2_instances) review.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you update.

I could solve the issue by adding a forward rule in iptables.

Initially there was forward rule like this in iptables.

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth0 -j f_reflected

Now i added forward rule for eth0

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0  -j ACCEPT

After that all nat request from network are getting routed and it working fine.

This is my postrouting rule for nat

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 172.30.37.0/24 -j MASQUERADE